# How can I influence the return type of a template class method based on some template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, metaprogramming

A template class should have a method who's return type is based on a template argument. In this example, how can I make the function return `int` (a copy) for `K=0` and `int&` (ref) for `K=1`?

```
template<typename T, int K>
class someclass
{
public:
    someclass() : member(3) { }
    T giveback() { return member; } // if K=0 should return by T, else return by T&
private:
    T member;
};

int main()
{
    someclass<int,0> x;
    x.giveback();
}
```

Comment: Note, I know that I could have template specialization. But are there other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Delegate to something else that's doing the specializing for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
typename std::conditional<K, T&, T>::type giveback() { return member; }
```

If `K` is 0 then the type will be `T`, otherwise it will be `T&`.

There isn't really any such thing as "without template specialization" though, since `std::conditional` is implemented using template specialization. Using `std::conditional` just helps you localize the template specialization and not have to duplicate large parts of your entire class.

Comment: "...and not have to duplicate large parts of your entire class." This is what i meant.

Comment: I thought it was worth mentioning that there is also the more succint `std::conditional_t`:
`std::conditional_t<K, T&, T> giveback() { return member; }`